# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.modeling.optimization'

Tags: tensorflow

Please give solution on the following error. The tricky part is that the verification and testing is running "OK" but when I run command for training it throws following error.

The system details are as follows

- Win10 - python 3.7.6
- cuda 10.1 cudnn - 7.6.5
- opencv - 4.5.1.48
- tensorflow / tensorflow-gpu ==2.2.0
- object_detection-0.1
- protoc - 3.17.3
- tf-models-official
- tensorflow-model-optimization

Paths are already created

(Working on jupyter notebook on TFOD-API)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line
> 32, in 
> from object_detection import model_lib_v2   File "D:\Code_kida\ANPR\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 31, in 
> from object_detection import model_lib   File "D:\Code_kida\ANPR\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_lib.py",
> line 34, in 
> from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder   File "D:\Code_kida\ANPR\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py",
> line 25, in 
> from official.modeling.optimization import ema_optimizer ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.modeling.optimization'

Comment: please add more tags and format your post

Comment: Hi @Ronak ,Have you tried latest versions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder "D:\Code_kida\ANPR\Tensorflow\models\official" is exist and it has "modeling/optimization/ema_optimizer.py" inside.
I had the same error and that was the fix for me. might work for you too. or whoever comes here in the future